# Anderer Name für ein selbst erstelltes Manöver im Schildkampf (in einem Fantasy-Rollenspiel)

Tags: single-word-request

Ich hab eine Sonderregel für ein Pen&Paper (Das Schwarze Auge, für die die es nicht kennen: Ein Fantasy-RPG) erstellt, die es einem Charakter ermöglicht, als Manöver quasi vor einen Verbündeten zu treten und diesen mit seinem Schild zu schützen. Wichtig ist dabei, dass der Schild relevant ist für dieses Manöver, welches sich nicht ohne einen Schild ausführen lässt.

Nun suche ich einen Namen für dieses Manöver, welcher passend zu den restlichen Sonderfertigkeiten und Manövern im Spiel klingt. Ein kleiner Auszug von anderen Manövern:

- Finte
- Ausfall
- Wuchtschlag
- gezielter Stich
- Defensiver/Offensiver Kampfstil
- Windmühle
- Binden

Der momentane Name "Schild-Interferenz" ist nur das erstbeste, was mir in den Sinn kam, und klingt überhaupt nicht passend, daher suche ich nun nach einer Alternative. Ich hoffe, diese Frage ist für diesen Stack nicht unpassend, als Suche nach Alternativen.

Comment: "Schildkröte" - Passt am ehesten zur "Windmühle"

Comment: Ich würde rauszufinden versuchen, welcher Gott in der Welt des Schwarzen Auges eine altruistische Ader hat und es dann ...s Schild nennen. Ich glaubte mich gut im Pantheon auszukennen, kann aber keinen Kandidaten nennen... Er oder sie darf natürlich nicht pazifistisch sein.

Comment: @Ludi ist eine Idee, allerdings handelt es sich ja um ein allerwelts-Manöver, und nicht um eine Liturgie oder ein Wunder, das ein Geweihter wirken könnte ;) Daher passt ein Götterbezug nicht so gut.

Comment: @Patta völlig richtig.

Comment: „Schutzschild“? Klingt für mich einfach und prägnant.

Comment: klingt aber eher nach einem Gegnstand, finde ich. Nicht nach einem Manöver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beschirmen, Abschirmung oder Deckung.

Comment: Solide. Nur vom Flankenschutz würde ich absehen, es sei denn es wäre genau dafür gedacht. Sonst führt das in der Spielrunde bei jedem Neuen zu Diskussionen, wenn einer von vorne decken will.

Comment: Genau ;) Aber "Abschirmung" klingt schonmal gut.

Comment: @Ludi "Flankenschutz" wollte ich auch nicht schreiben, aber die Software ermahnte mich, dass 24 Zeichen zu wenig sei. Ich klaue "Deckung" von Matthias. :)

Comment: Wie wäre es mit Blockade?

Comment: klingt für mich zu statisch, das klingt eher nach "während ich in dieser Tür stehe, kommt niemand durch!"

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde parallelen zu Kriegstaktik und Formationen suchen. Welche Begriffe werden verwendet, wenn ein Soldat einen anderen schützt. Mir ist hier nur Deckung bzw. "Deckung geben" eingefallen. Daher folgende Vorschläge:

- Freundesschild
- Schildfreund
- Schilddeckung

Comment: Das behalte ich auf jeden Fall im Hinterkopf für ein Manöver, welches tatäschlich gegen Fernangriffe nutzbar ist, dafür klingt es besser, finde ich.